# Getting errors Power::infy and Infinity::indet while running a For-loop

Tags: numerics, warning-messages

My program gives the above-mentioned errors when I run the loop more than 3 times. It is a 4th order iterative method of Ostrowski family.

```
Plot[Exp[x] - 2, {x, -5, 5}]

fx = Exp[x] - 2;
f1x = Exp[x];
fy = Exp[y] - 2;
fxn1 = Exp[xn1] - 2;
x = 0.6'35;
xnv = {};
fxn = {fx};
For[i = 1, i <= 4,

 y = x - (fx*f1x)/(f1x^2 + fx^2);

 xn1 = x - 1/2*(fx*f1x)/(f1x^2 + fx^2)*(1 + fx/(fx - 2*fy));
 AppendTo[xnv, xn1]

 x = xn1;
 AppendTo[fxn, fx]
  i++
 ]
Print["value of x is equal to ", x]
coc = Log[Abs[fxn[[3]]/fxn[[2]]]]/Log[Abs[fxn[[2]]/fxn[[1]]]];
Print["coc is equal to ", coc]
Quit[]
```

Comment: Instructions within the for look need to be separated by `;`. A space indicates multiplication. Even after fixing that, though, the result is indeterminate. What are you trying to do?

Comment: This is a fourth order iterative method and I have to find root of the equation with accuracy of 35 significant figures.

Comment: the quantity `fx/(fx - 2*fy)` becomes indeterminate as both `x` and `y` numerically approach `Log[2]` (presumably the solution). You should probably fix your algorithm to avoid computing that quantity.

Comment: side comment, stringing a bunch of zeros on the initial `x` doesnt give higher precision. You should do ``x=0.6`35``.  After that you do not need `SetAccuracy`, the extended precision will follow since the initial `x` is the only floating number in the problem.

Comment: Ohhh....I'll try that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You get those error messages because your algorithm converges to `x == Log[2]` so fast that you really don't want to iterate four times.

Let's look at your code in a cleaner form.

```
fx[x_] := Exp[x] - 2
f1x[x_] := Exp[x]
y[x_] := x - (fx[x]*f1x[x])/(f1x[x]^2 + fx[x]^2)
xn[x_] := 
  x - 1/2*(fx[x]*f1x[x])/(f1x[x]^2 + fx[x]^2)*(1 + fx[x]/(fx[x] - 2*fx[y[x]]))

x0 = 0.6`36;
Module[{x, xv, fv},
  xv = {x0};
  fv = {fx[x0]};
  For[i = 1, i <= 4, i++,
    x = xn[xv[[i]]];
    AppendTo[xv, x]; AppendTo[fv, fx[x]]];
  Transpose @ {xv, fv}]
```

> Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0.*10^-34 ComplexInfinity encountered.
>   Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0.*10^-34 encountered.
>
> ```
> {{0.600000000000000000000000000000000000, -0.17788119960949102512463233183713549},  
>  {0.69311715333638072739341638011885481, -0.00006005354550403350594508637314563}, 
>  {0.6931471805599453090446452647720226, -7.451737133723080*10^-19}, 
>  {0.6931471805599453094172321214581766, 0.*10^-34}, 
>  {Indeterminate, Indeterminate}}
> ```

You can see convergence was complete on the 3rd iteration, but your For-loop didn't stop there.

Here is some code that will solve your problem in Mathematica's functional style and which will automatically detect the convergence.

```
next[{x_, _}] := Module[{u = xn[x]}, {u, fx[u]}]
FixedPoint[next, {x0, fx[x0]}, SameTest -> (Abs[#2[[2]]] < 10^-30 &)] // First
```

> ```
> 0.6931471805599453094172321214581766
> ```

Also note that to carry out a high precision computation, all I had to do was define `x0` as a high-precision, inexact number with `` x0 = 0.6`36 ``.

#### Update

The modified For-loop version of the OP's code shown above only requires a test for convergence to be added to eliminate the errors messages. Here is the code with such a test installed.

```
x0 = 0.6`36;
ϵ = 10^-30;
Module[{x, f, xv, fv},
  xv = {x0};
  fv = {fx[x0]};
  For[i = 1, i <= 4, i++,
    x = xn[xv[[i]]];
    f = fx[x];
    AppendTo[xv, x]; AppendTo[fv, f];
    If[Abs[f] < ϵ, Break[]]];
  Transpose @ {xv, fv}]
```

> ```
> {0.600000000000000000000000000000000000, -0.17788119960949102512463233183713549}, 
> {0.69311715333638072739341638011885481, -0.00006005354550403350594508637314563}, 
> {0.6931471805599453090446452647720226, -7.451737133723080*10^-19}, 
> {0.6931471805599453094172321214581766, 0.*10^-34}}
> ```

Comment: My problem isn't to about finding the solution of the equation but rather about how to program an iterative method, that is why I can't use FixedPoint.
Thanks for the help though

Comment: @user49702. The For-loop I wrote only needs to apply the convergence test I used in the `FixedPoint` example to get rid of the error messages. I show how to do install such a test in the update I just made.